# Matplotlib plot draws straight line, doesn't show correct y-values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to plot the season on the x-axis and the Greens in Regulation % on the y-axis. The plot is incorrectly showing up like this:

[incorrect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmO08.png)

[dj dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96rCg.png)

How can I get matplotlib to plot the correct y-axis values?

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pga = pd.read_csv('/Users/dpericks/Desktop/PGA_Data_Historical.csv')
dj = pga[(pga['Player Name'] == 'Dustin Johnson')
    & (pga['Variable'] == 'Greens in Regulation Percentage - (%)')]
plt.plot(dj['Season'], dj['Value'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

pga = pd.read_csv('PGA_Data_Historical.csv')
dj = pga[(pga['Player Name'] == 'Dustin Johnson')
    & (pga['Variable'] == 'Greens in Regulation Percentage - (%)')]
dj_numberic_values_ = pd.to_numeric(dj['Value'])
plt.plot(dj['Season'], dj_numberic_values_)
plt.show()
```

When I debugged your code, I realized that we get `string type` variables from `dj['Value']`. I had to convert these values to appropriate numerical values so that `matplotlib` can work with them. I hope it helps your problem.